# Retrofit2 skipping inner elements in JSON repsonse

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I recently upgraded my Retrofit library from version 1 to 2 in my Android project and suddenly various mappings throughout my project are failing to map. I have nulls in places I didn't use to have nulls and I can only surmise it's from failed mappings.

I realized that Retrofit2 is skipping the inner elements/attributes of my JSON response. So, for instance, action is being skipped here

Here is an instance - I have not touched this class since upgrading retrofit and the JSON response has not changed.

```
public final class BXActionInfo extends BXBaseObject {

@SerializedName("_id")
private String id;
@JsonAdapter(ActionEntityTypeJsonAdapter.class)
private ActionEntityType entityType;
private List<BXActionReference> references;
private String referenceClientTitle;

...various getters and setters
```

And here is my API response (the portion that should be mapping to this class):

```
_id": "5bcdf558b876ea01003ff581",
"text": "Camp Care Package!",
"subText": "Build your own!",
"position": 0,
"action": {
    "_id": "5bcdf558b876ea01003ff582",
    "entityType": 22,
    "references": [
    {
        "referenceType": 12,
        "product": null,
        "variant": null,
        "productId": null,
        "variantId": null,
        "category": null,
        "softCategory": null,
        "orderId": null,
        "url": null,
        "promoCode": null,
        "searchTerm": null,
        "brandId": null,
        "occassionId": "5aec8040bb944d0100d14038",
        "_id": "5bcdf571d43cea01005a18e2"
    }
    ],
    "referenceClientTitle": ""
},
"isExpressOnly": false
```

Again, has anything changed in the way retrofit maps since version 2? There must be something because my code has not changed.

Edit:

Here is BXActionReference:

```
public final class BXActionReference extends BXBaseObject {

public enum ActionEntityType {
    ACTIONTYPELISTENTITIES, /***/
    ACTIONTYPEPRODUCT, /***/
    ACTIONTYPEVARIANT, /***/
    ACTIONTYPEURL, /***/
    ACTIONTYPENOREFERENCE, /***/
    ACTIONTYPESOFTCATEGORY, /***/
    ACTIONTYPEPRODUCTCATEGORY, /***/
    ACTIONTYPEORDERCREATED, /***/
    ACTIONTYPEORDERSHIPPED, /***/
    ACTIONTYPEORDERDELIVERED, /***/
    ACTIONTYPEORDERCANCELLED, /***/
    ACTIONTYPEEXPRESSORDERDELIVERED, /***/
    ACTIONTYPEEXPRESSORDERCONFIRMED, /***/
    ACTIONTYPEEXPRESSORDERCOMPLETESHOPPING, /***/
    ACTIONTYPEGIFTCARDORDER, /***/
    ACTIONTYPEGIFTCARDCANCELLED, /***/
    ACTIONTYPEPROMOCODE, /***/
    ACTIONTYPESEARCHRESULTS, /***/
    ACTIONTYPEIMAGE, /***/
    ACTIONTYPESMILEIMAGE, /***/
    ACTIONJOINLOGINACCOUNT
}
@SerializedName("_id")
@Expose
protected String id;
protected String url;
protected int referenceType;
protected String orderId;
protected BXVariant variant;
protected BXProduct product;
protected String variantId;
protected String productId;
protected BXRootSoftCategory softCategory;
protected BXRootCategoryChild category;
protected String promoCode;
protected String searchTerm;
protected String brandId;
protected String occassionId;

//setters and getters here...
```

And here is my Retrofit builder:

```
Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .client(okHttpClient2.build())
            .build();
```

Comment: Could I see your BXActionReference?
Also your retrofit builder?

Comment: I have added both to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from Retrofit 1 to 2 is not cut and dry, unfortunately. From just looking at this code I don't see anything that stands out to me as incorrect, but most recommended a full rewrite of your service layer when retrofit 2 came out.

I would recommend following this great post by Sasa Sekulic that shows how to make the change step by step to determine where your breaking changes were.

https://medium.com/@sasa_sekulic/quick-and-easy-guide-to-retrofit-2-0-setup-or-migration-with-rxjava-ab7a11bc17df

Comment: I followed this guide already and made the necessary changes.